# is there a unique identifier that i can use in rails that is not session[:session_id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to track `kiss_metrics` identifier and would like to maintain the same `unique_identifier` for the user throughout their entire time they are on the site, even after call `reset_session`.

Something like a `cookie_id` that is the same from login to logout and the entire time they are on the site?

Comment: you might be able to use the csrf token as an identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

First, add your own token to the session on login using [SecureRandom.uuid](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom#uuid-class_method). Doing this makes sure it's not going to get messed with by other parts of Rails (you don't know when the csrf token gets nuked, for example).

Instead of calling `reset_session` call a wrapper that maintains your unique token:

```
def clear_session_except_token
  token = session[:token]
  clear_session
  session[:token] = token
end
```

You can then clear the token when the user logs out.